# Morse to English program-function calling

Tags: python

This is a program which converts Morse code to English text.

I am having trouble converting the morse code to English. All I get for the output is asterisks. I have another function that converts from string to morse. It seems like the `decodeMorsetoChar(text_input)` function is not getting the converted morse code to convert back to English.

```py
def encodeStringtoMorse(text_input):
    
    length=len(text_input)
    string=''
    for x in range(0, length):
        char= encodeChartoMorse(text_input[x])
        string=string + '    ' + char

    return string 
        
def decodeMorsetoChar(text_input):
    
    morse=encodeStringtoMorse(text_input.upper())
    if morse== ".-" :
        morse = "A"
    elif morse== "-..." :
        morse = "B"
    elif morse== "-.-." :
        morse = "C"
    elif morse== "-.." :
        morse = "D"
    elif morse== ".":
        morse = "E"
    elif morse== "..-." :
        morse = "F"
    elif morse== "--.":
        morse = "G"
    elif morse== "...." :
        morse = "H"
    elif morse== ".." :
        morse = "I"
    elif morse== ".---" :
        morse = "J"
    elif morse== "-.-":
        morse = "K"
    elif morse== ".-..":
        morse = "L"
    elif morse== "--" :
        morse = "M"
    elif morse== "-.":
        morse = "N"
    elif morse== "---":
        morse = "O"
    elif morse== ".--.":
        morse = "P"
    elif morse== "--.-":
        morse = "Q"
    elif morse==".-.":
        morse = "R"
    elif morse== "..." :
        morse = "S"
    elif morse== "-":
        morse = "T"
    elif morse== "..-":
        morse = "U"
    elif morse== "...-":
        morse = "V"
    elif morse== ".--" :
        morse = "W"
    elif morse== "-..-" :
        morse = "X"
    elif morse== "-.--":
        morse = "Y"
    elif morse== "--.." :
        morse = "Z"
    else:
        morse= '*'
    
        
    return morse


def decodeMorsetoString(text_input):
    
    listt=''
    morsecode=decodeMorsetoChar(text_input)
    for morse in text_input.split():
        morsecode=decodeMorsetoChar(text_input)
        listt= listt+morsecode
        
    return listt
```

Comment: advice: create a mapping dict where each key is the morse string and each value is the uppercase letter, to decode. You could then use the same dict but inverting keys and values to encode. It'll make your code much cleaner.   Then to decode you'd do res = mapping.get(str_value, *)

Comment: I have not learned about dictionaries, we are learning about them next

Comment: fair enough but after that, do it ;-)

Comment: also python function/methods should all use snake case, not camelcase

Comment: You are doing `morsecode=decodeMorsetoChar(text_input)` which passes the ***whole*** text. But you do this in a loop and it's supposed to be `morsecode=decodeMorsetoChar(morse)`

Comment: tomerikoo, I am getting a name error.

Comment: Then you need to read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre] so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Here's my refactor of Jalen's answer:

```
morse_alphabet = {
    'A': ".-",
    'B': "-...",
    'C': "-.-.",
    'D': "-..",
    'E': ".",
    'F': "..-.",
    'G': "--.",
    'H': "....",
    'I': "..",
    'J': ".---",
    'K': "-.-",
    'L': ".-..",
    'M': "--",
    'N': "-.",
    'O': "---",
    'P': ".--.",
    'Q': "--.-",
    'R': ".-.",
    'S': "...",
    'T': "-",
    'U': "..-",
    'V': "...-",
    'W': ".--",
    'X': "-..-",
    'Y': "-.--",
    'Z': "--..",
}
alphabet_morse = {v: k for k, v in morse_alphabet.items()}


def string_to_morse(text):
    return ''.join([morse_alphabet.get(c.upper(), '*') for c in text])


def morse_to_string(morse):
    return ''.join([alphabet_morse[m] for m in morse.split('*')])


string_to_morse("Hello world")
morse_to_string("-..-*--..")
```

Comment: Nice answer for putting in the effort to refactor the code, but that would leave it at a code review-level answer. I upvoted your answer, but maybe edit it to include what you actually fixed/chanted? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
morseAlphabet = {
'A': ".-",
'B': "-...",
'C': "-.-.",
'D': "-..",
'E': ".",
'F': "..-.",
'G': "--.",
'H': "....",
'I': "..",
'J': ".---",
'K': "-.-",
'L': ".-..",
'M': "--",
'N': "-.",
'O': "---",
'P': ".--.",
'Q': "--.-",
'R': ".-.",
'S': "...",
'T': "-",
'U': "..-",
'V': "...-",
'W': ".--",
'X': "-..-",
'Y': "-.--",
'Z': "--..",
'Default': "*"
}


def decodeMorsetoChar(text_input):
    list_chars = list(text_input)
    morse_string = ''
    for char in list_chars:
        try:
            morse_string += morseAlphabet[char.upper()]
        except:
            morse_string += "*"

    return morse_string


def decodeMorsetoString(morse_input):
    list_morse = list(morse_input.split('*'))
    string_from_morse = ''
    # for morse in list_morse:
        # for key in morseAlphabet:
        #     if morseAlphabet[key] == morse:
        #         string_from_morse += key
    alphabet_morse = {v: k for k, v in morseAlphabet.items()}

    for code in list_morse:
        string_from_morse += alphabet_morse[code]

    return string_from_morse


decodeMorsetoChar("Hello world")
decodeMorsetoString("-..-*--..")
```

Comment: why would you go over each key of the dict to find the one matching morse instead of generating anotehr dict from your dict where key=value and value=key ;-) Then you can do dict.get(morse, <default value if not found>) it's easy: `alphabet_morse = {v: k for k, v in morse_alphabet.items()}`

Comment: thx, but i am not supposed to use dictionaries